# Kendo Grid , cell edit -> how to set selected ID from autocomplete to model for update action?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have following column and model definition in Kendo Grid:

```
 schema: {
                model: {     parentProject: {
                                editable: true,
                                nullable: false,
                                type: "string"
                            },

columns: [

{
                    field :"parentProject",
                    title : $translate.instant('PARENT_PROJECT'),
                    editor: GlobalHelperService.getProjectsListForAutocomplete,
                    width: 250,
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "contains"
                        }
                    }
                },
```

And I have this following for Autocomplete over column defined above.

```
this.getProjectsListForAutocomplete =  function (container, options) {
         var input = $('<input id= "selecteditem" data-bind= "value:' +  options.field + '" />');
         input.appendTo(container);
         input.kendoAutoComplete({
             dataSource :  {
                 type: "json",
                 serverFiltering: true,
                 transport: {
                     read: function (options) {
                         console.log("List");
                         console.log(options.data);
                         requestParams = {
                             "entityName": "project",
                             "page": 1,
                             "pageSize": 20,
                             "filter": options.data.filter,
                             "sort": [
                                 {
                                     "field": "dic",
                                     "ord": "asc"
                                 }
                             ]
                         };
                         ApiService.doHttpRequest(
                             "POST",
                             $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "project/search",
                             requestParams
                         )
                             .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                 // successful data retrieval
                                 console.log("request success, checking state");
                                 console.log(data);
                                 // sent status to global HTTP status service
                                 var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                                 console.log("Status response is " + jsonResponse.result);
                                 // do something with data
                                 switch (jsonResponse.result) {
                                     case true:
                                         options.success(data.results);
                                         break;
                                     case false:
                                         growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('LIST_LOADING_ERROR'), 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                         break;
                                 }
                             })
                             .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                 var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                                 console.log("Processing error with status " +status);
                                 growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('PROCESSING_REQUEST_ERROR') + jsonResponse.message , 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                 // hide loading spinner
                                 kendo.ui.progress(gridView, false);
                             });
                     }
                 }
             },
             dataTextField: "name"  ,
             dataValueField: "id",
             filter: "contains",
             minLength: 1,
             change  : function (e) {
                 console.log("change");
                 //console.log(e);
                 //gridView.closeCell();
             },
             select  : function (e) {
                 console.log("select");
                 var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
                 console.log(dataItem);
                 return dataItem;
             }
         });
     };
```

Problem is that after the change of the cell content by selecting item from autocomplete is in model updated selected name instead of the ID.

It means that selected value from Autocomplete should replace item in model, so in update request will have  item **parentProject** value of the selected ID.

How can I do it?

EDIT:

I tried to do this by this way, but without luck.

```
 change  : function (e) {
                 console.log("change");
                 //console.log(e);
                 //gridView.closeCell();
                 e.sender.value("New Value");
                 options.model.set(options.field, "123");
             },
```

It always changed only text in cell.

Comment: Really Nobody knows?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

i am not exactly getting you.

but what i get is you must Specify id and fields in schema model.

```
   schema: {
               model: {
                  id: "YOUR PROJECT ID",
                  fields: {
                            parentProject: {
                                    editable: true,
                                    nullable: false,
                                    type: "string"
                             }
                          }
                      }
              }
```

hope its help

Comment: I have this in configuration.